# Movies in movies

Tags: riddle, movies

Each clue references a movie. Take all of the clues, combine them, and solve that clue to get you one final movie.

Where did the literally animated little guy and his family come from?
What type was 2 less than the first 23rd?
Who was the botanist that shook the earth with his finger?
TECHNICOLOR! without the earth or the obviousness.
The aliens are almost extinct.
'ey you, hand, lose the glasses!
2 more and then...

Good luck!

Comment: If somebody solves this with clues as vague as "Where did the animated little guy and his family come from?" I will be absolutely amazed. I don't mean this as an insult to the riddle.

Comment: @IfTrue I edited the clue to emphasize the meaning of little guy... can you give me a few more suggestions? I'm starting to overestimate the puzzling community.

Comment: @awesomepi - I think that IfTrue is trying to say that that clue (and several others) can fit a myriad of solutions.  (e.g. animated little guy could refer to Stuart Little, Steamboat Mickey, Bart Simpson, Woody, Tiny Tim, and Tetsuo (Akira), to name just a small few that could potentially fit.  The issue is trying to find a common thread (if there is one) between the movies.

Comment: The common thread might be movies that have a clip from another movie inside the movie. Home Alone wouldn't count because the movie he watches was created for the film. But in You've Got Mail, for example, there are references to The Godfather... (and I think that's where "'ey you, hand, lose the glasses!" comes from)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am going to start a community answer.  Anyone have any ideas??

> I was thinking that the movies all have some sort of abbreviation in the title, and then the letters could be used in the final answer. With the clues referencing space, and the ET answer, it seems that all of the movies can be space based. Might be a route to go down.

Where did the animated little guy and his family come from?

> Possibly the Secret of N.I.M.H.

What type was 2 less than the first 23rd?

> V for Vendetta (the 23rd letter of the alphabet is W.  Take away two legs of the W, and you get a V)

Who was the botanist that shook the earth with his finger?

> E.T. The Extra Terrestial (he was a botanist and his finger was magical)

TECHNICOLOR! without the earth or the obviousness.

> Maybe 2001: A Space Odyssey <-- the clue, but not the theme above.  Not sure if the theme is correct, so leaving here.  Thanks to @JGibbers

The aliens are almost extinct.

> Titan A.E.  (In this movie, humans have become the aliens, and are nearly extinct)

Hey you, hand, lose the glasses!

> 

2 more and then...

> 

Comment: You can make it a "real" community answer by checking the "Community Wiki" mark to the bottom right when you edit the answer.

Comment: @StewieGriffin.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: It says "literally animated little guy" - maybe that means "animated" like "energetic"?

Comment: I was thinking The Indian in the Cupboard, for literally animated. (it was a book first, he's a little guy, the cupboard animates him, it's a rather good fit)

Comment: Feels like `'ey you` implies Gold in the movie title.